# Is there any way to know which groovy version used in grails project?

Tags: grails, groovy

From grails project, we can know which grails version used .Like that can i get groovy version?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can look in the install directory under lib. For example in Grails 2.2.3 it's `lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/jars/groovy-all-2.0.8.jar` so the version is 2.0.8.

If you want to find the value programmatically at runtime, call `GroovySystem.getVersion()` to get the current version string.

Comment: What's the best way to set Groovy version for a grails project?

Comment: You can't - Grails ships with the version of Groovy that it works with and the dependency is low-level enough that it is difficult/impossible to change